# What is the probability that for n points sampled from interval in R, they will all be larger than other n points sampled from same interval

Tags: probability

From solving some probability questions, i have encountered a probably simple question i have yet to solve. The question was formulated for $N_a=N_b=2$  but i present a more general one.
Please share an answer also for $N_a=N_b$ or $N_a=N_b=2$ if you find one.

Sampling 2 sets of points {$A_{i=1}^{N_a}$}, {$B_{i=1}^{N_b}$} sampled from an interval $I\in \mathbb{R}$,
what is the probability that $min(A) > max(B)$

Comment: An equivalent way of choosing $A$ and $B$ is to first choosing $N_a + N_b$ points in $I$, then choosing some subset of them (of size $N_a$) to be set $A$ (the remaining points will constitute $B$). Does this make things simpler?

Comment: @paulinho You should make it the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the sets $A$ and $B$ are chosen via independent draws according to some continuous probability distribution $\mu$ defined on $I$. It turns out that if this is the case, the probability that $A$ is wholly greater than $B$ (i.e. $\min(A) > \max(B)$) is actually independent of $\mu$!

The reason is because another way to choose $A$ and $B$ is first to choose $A \cup B$, by making $N_a + N_b$ draws from $I$ according $\mu$. Note that since $\mu$ is continuous, with probability $1$ we have $|A \cup B| = N_a + N_b$ (with probability $1$, we don't draw an element twice). We can then choose any $N_a$ of the elements to comprise set $A$ and leave the rest to be in set $B$. Given any choice of $|A \cup B|$, we can construct $A$ and $B$ in ${N_a + N_b \choose N_a}$ ways.

Note that only one of these choices of $A$ and $B$, namely the one where the elements of $A$ are chosen to be the $N_a$ largest elements of $A \cup B$, yields a configuration where $\min(A) > \max(B)$. This holds true for any choice of $A \cup B$, so indeed the desired event happens with probability
$$\frac{1}{N_a + N_b \choose N_a}$$
Note that everything goes out the window if there is no assumption of independence.

Comment: Wow very elegant! Thanks!